# Marshalling a Notification Parcel

Tags: android, notifications, marshalling, parcel

I'm trying to write a Notification object to a File.
The best way I could find was to write the object to a parcel, marshall that parcel to get a byte[] and then write it to a file.

```
Parcel notif = Parcel.obtain();
notification.writeToParcel(notif, 0);
byte[] notifArray = notif.marshall();
```

I get a Runtime exception when I try to marshall the parcel though:
    "Tried to marshall a Parcel that contained Binder objects."

Is there a better way of writing Notification objects to file? Else, how do I get this approach to work?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? We have a similar issue.

Comment: No. I'm aftraid not.
Working on something else right now. Might get back to it if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

The notification contains a live/active binder object. It wasn't built to be used for saving the state (in a byte[]) rather it implements Parcelable for IPC purposes. You should ideally save the necessary fields rather than the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way is to store the information from the notification. The value of Binder object cannot be stored because it will be changed.