# How do I save a pending intent locally on the phone

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I need to store the PendingIntent object I'm getting from a StatusBarNotification object.    PendingIntent pendingIntent=sbn.getNotification().contentIntent;

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661268/marshalling-a-notification-parcel

Comment: This was posted way back in 2012. There still doesn't seem to be a concrete solution to this. Would be interesting to solve this, what say @DavidWasser?

Comment: @TerrelLewis have you had any luck with this? I'm trying to do the same (store notification intent for future launches), but can't seem to find any solid references even after years of your question :(

Comment: @fonix232 Sorry mate, haven't found a way yet to persist pending intents. I'm just holding the pending intents in a service, which means they will be available as long as the service is alive

Answer (score 3):

read from:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.readPendingIntentOrNullFromParcel(parcel);
```

write to:

```
PendingIntent.writePendingIntentOrNullToParcel(PendingIntent,parcel);
```

**edit 1:**

> *Parcels cannot be saved right? @ceph3us – Terrel Lewis*

You can "Save"  Parcelable or Parcel

```
Parcelable -----> 
         Parcel.obtain() ----->
                Parcelable.writeToParcel(Parcel,0) ----->  // write to parcel 
                     Parcel.marshal() ----- >  byte[]
```

then bytes can by saved to file database or any other persistent or not data storage. One thing that you can't do is marshall the parcelable that contains IBinder object read more :

- **[what is Binder in android](http://www.programering.com/a/MjMyMDMwATQ.html)**
- **[android binder - ipc](https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/cs282/PDFs/android-binder-ipc.pdf)**

before you marshall a object class you need to remove binder  - binder reference  is stored in kernel space. If binder comes from you you should easily create new one and assign to unmarshaled data later.

> *...and as such does not attempt to maintain compatibility with data
>   created in different versions of the platform. – @FindOutIslamNow*

question was: How do I save a pending intent **locally on the phone**

in my answer there was remedy on IBinder - by removing kernel binder driver depending part from parcel we are free to use the rest of the data which are nothing more than bytes!

We can also take what we want from Pending intent and recreate it self (parcel is nothing more like container for our data and the IBinder is a transport mechanism for it a shell of IPC implementation from linux kernel binder driver similar to more known 2endpoints socket transport.

Both (the data in container aka parcel and the binder) are known as pending intent - think of it like pipeline of carrying watter - when you remove a pipe from it you get the water but you can't transport it any more :) like before from source to the destination point.

As binder has own lifespan and in most cases it can not be saved think of it like phone call where one side does not hang up (hoping it'll come back after some time) while the other can't continue call anymore because from it's age is passing away! so the connection is broken and can't be used anymore.

Comment: From `marshal()` docs: `he data you retrieve here must not be placed in any kind of persistent storage (on local disk, across a network, etc). For that, you should use standard serialization or another kind of general serialization mechanism. The Parcel marshalled representation is highly optimized for local IPC, and as such does not attempt to maintain compatibility with data created in different versions of the platform.`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to store pending intent for the time being service is running .....make use of hashmap and store key in database which is equivalent to pendingintent and make method in service returning the hashmap ....and now with key you can easily access pending intent if it persists.

Answer (score 0):

A solution which is working for **own produced** PendingIntents (prevents "java.lang.RuntimeException: Tried to marshall a Parcel that contained Binder objects."):

```
public class PersistentPendingIntent implements Parcelable
{
    private enum PendingIntentType{SERVICE, BROADCAST, ACTIVITY}
    @NonNull
    private final PendingIntentType pendingIntentType;
    protected final int requestCode;
    protected final int flags;
    @NonNull
    protected final Intent intent;

    private PersistentPendingIntent(@NonNull PendingIntentType pendingIntentType, int requestCode, @NonNull Intent intent, int flags)
    {
        this.pendingIntentType = pendingIntentType;
        this.flags = flags;
        this.intent = intent;
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
    }

    @Nullable
    public PendingIntent getPendingIntent(@NonNull Context context)
    {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
        switch (pendingIntentType)
        {
            case SERVICE:
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, requestCode, intent, flags);
                break;
            case BROADCAST:
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, flags);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY:
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, intent, flags);
                break;
        }
        return pendingIntent;
    }


    public static PersistentPendingIntent getService(int requestCode, @NonNull Intent intent, int flags)
    {
        return new PersistentPendingIntent(PendingIntentType.SERVICE, requestCode, intent, flags);
    }

    public static PersistentPendingIntent getActivity(int requestCode, @NonNull Intent intent, int flags)
    {
        return new PersistentPendingIntent(PendingIntentType.ACTIVITY, requestCode, intent, flags);
    }

    public static PersistentPendingIntent getBroadcast(int requestCode, @NonNull Intent intent, int flags)
    {
        return new PersistentPendingIntent(PendingIntentType.BROADCAST, requestCode, intent, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeInt(this.pendingIntentType.ordinal());
        dest.writeInt(this.requestCode);
        dest.writeInt(this.flags);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.intent, flags);
    }

    protected PersistentPendingIntent(Parcel in)
    {
        int tmpPendingIntentType = in.readInt();
        this.pendingIntentType = PendingIntentType.values()[tmpPendingIntentType];
        this.requestCode = in.readInt();
        this.flags = in.readInt();
        this.intent = in.readParcelable(Intent.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Creator<PersistentPendingIntent> CREATOR = new Creator<PersistentPendingIntent>()
    {
        @Override
        public PersistentPendingIntent createFromParcel(Parcel source)
        {
            return new PersistentPendingIntent(source);
        }

        @Override
        public PersistentPendingIntent[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new PersistentPendingIntent[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
PersistentPendingIntent persistentPendingIntent = PersistentPendingIntent.getService(REQUEST_CANCEL, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

// Serialization
Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
parcel.writeValue(persistentPendingIntent);
byte[] serializedPersistentPendingIntent = parcel.marshall();
parcel.recycle();

// Deserialization
parcel.unmarshall(serializedPersistentPendingIntent, 0, serializedPersistentPendingIntent.length);
parcel.setDataPosition(0);
persistentPendingIntent = (PersistentPendingIntent) parcel.readValue(PersistentPendingIntent.class.getClassLoader());

PendingIntent pendingIntent = persistentPendingIntent.getPendingIntent(context);
```

Answer (score -2):

A `PendingIntent` can be serialized to a byte stream since it is `Parcelable`. Create a `Parcel`, call `writeToParcel()` on the `PendingIntent` to serialize the object into the `Parcel`, then call `marshall()` on the `Parcel` to get the bytes, which you can then write to a file on the device.

NOTE: The `Parcelable` interface isn't designed for long-term persistence, so this may not work in all cases. It depends on what you want to use it for.

Comment: Thanks @DavidWasser for the response. I did try this approach and I got an error: Tried to marshall a Parcel that contained Binder objects. How do I overcome this?

Comment: Sorry, you can't. There are some things that can be put into a `Parcel` that cannot be serialized. Why are you trying to do this? Perhaps we can find another way to solve your problem.

Comment: I need to save the pendingintent I'm receiving from other applications' notifications in order to be able to launch them from my application at a later time. @DavidWasser

Comment: I came across a github link that serializes pendingintents:
[link](https://github.com/8tory/json2notification/blob/master/json2notification/src/main/java/com/bluelinelabs/logansquare/typeconverters/PendingIntentConverter.java)
But I'm having difficulty using the Jsoncreator and JsonParser. Could you help me with it?  @DavidWasser

Comment: You should open another question with your problems about the Jsoncreator. It will get more attention. I can't help you with that, sorry. I assume that you won't be able to successfully serialize a `PendingIntent` that contains a `Binder` for the same reason that you can't marshall ` PendingIntent` that contains a `Binder`.